# Bake Sound to F-Curve lags audio unless I disable another object in viewport

Tags: audio

This one literally is a hair-puller, because if I disable the characters hair mesh (in Viewport), the sound baked to F-Curve works fine.  But if I enable the unrelated hair mesh to show in Viewport, the mouth movements slow down to about half speed and falls behind the audio.

[image]

It also turns out that if I remove "enough" vertices from the hair mesh, the audio and mouth motion starts to synch up!

UPDATE: If I remove all of the Shape Keys from the hair object vertices, everything is now synched properly on the Character Mesh Object.  I don't understand why one objects vertex groups would interfere with another's.  At least I have a workaround for now.

[image]

This is a sample [image] file.

Comment: Sounds like a simple lag problem. Is the hair high poly?

Comment: i just downloaded your file and hit play and there was no lag problem. Or do i have to do something with it? you can check my result here: https://youtu.be/3Xe4Ynldvh0

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard -- Oddly, if I remove all of the Shape Keys from the hair object vertices, everything is now synched properly on the Character Mesh Object !

Comment: @Chris -- thanks for posting the video for any doubters!  I tried again on a download of my upload but I still see the problem in v2.93.    I'm editing my question with new information... if I remove all of the Shape Keys from the hair object vertices, everything is now synched properly on the Character Mesh Object.  It's a head-scratcher but I now have an acceptable workaround.